# media queries for IE

Tags: css, media-queries

Help me please.
It does not work in IE!

```
 <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/global.css">
```

file global.css

```
body{ background-color:black}
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
body{background-color:red;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
body{background-color:green;}
}
```

But It works:

```
 <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<style>
body{ background-color:black}
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
body{background-color:red;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
body{background-color:green;}
}
</style>
```

may have other solutions?

Comment: Are you sure that the path to your CSS file is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [homepage](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) of the css3 mediaqueries support script you are using, it only supports inline scripts, and not external and imported scripts.

Comment: please tell me which supports.

Comment: @zloctb If you look on the homepage (http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) of the support script, you will see in the description that it only supports inline styles. In other words, so long as your css styles are in `<style>` tags in your main html, they will be parsed and support added.

Comment: Wow... that's kind of useless. Then again, it hasn't been updated in years. @zloctb: I suggest looking for alternatives, like respond.js.